# Flutterfire Configure - Unhandled exception and no firebase initialization

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to configure firebase on MacOS with the new method shown on official docs as below:

```
firebase login
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutter fire configure
```

It generates the below error. I searched for this and didn't find any solution. can you help?

please note flutter doctor show no errors in any category and the same project is working on android using the google.infoplist file correctly. I am facing this issue with the new initialization method on MacOS only.\

Error:

```
username@192 MyApp % flutterfire configure
i Found 3 Firebase projects. Selecting project [Myappname]                                                                                                           
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios                                                                 
i Firebase android app [app-package] registered.                                                                                                                          
i Firebase ios app [app-package] registered.                                                                                                                              
Unhandled exception:
Exception: /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:88:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:88:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

#0      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:540:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (file:///Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterfire_cli-0.2.7/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Is this happening on a mac?

Comment: yes, MacBook Pro m1.

Comment: try `flutterfire configure`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing this in your terminal
 `gem install xcodeproj`

If you end up getting a permission error please consider running

```
sudo chown -R <your_user> $HOME/.rbenv
```

OR

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

Those with Mac's silicone...please update to the latest ruby version

Comment: thanks, I saw this solution in a different thread, when I use it it generate this error Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/sheriffsaidelahl/.local/share/gem/specs

Comment: Cool! This means that you access s not authorised. so try adding `sudo` before the `gem` hope you are the owner of the session.

Comment: did the two commands, still the same issue, I can figure out how I have no permission

Comment: Run this command `brew doctor` and see and run suggested commands from it

Comment: I installed the Xcodeproj using brew like this "brew install Xcodeproj"

Comment: show I rerun "flutterfire configure" ?

Comment: I did it again, it is still same issue :(

Comment: did you run brew doctor?

Comment: yes, saying your system is ready to brew, no errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252202/discussion-between-davis-and-mark-nugromentry).